# How to remove zero after the comma in a plot

Tags: plotting, numerics

Please, how to remove the 15 zeros after the comma and keep only one digit in the plot below?

[image]

This is the code for example

```
 Table[{n, n}, {n, 10^-2, 1.4, 2. 10^-1}]

 (* {{0.01, 0.01}, {0.21, 0.21}, {0.41, 0.41}, {0.6100000000000001,0.6100000000000001}, {0.81, 0.81}, {1.01, 1.01}, {1.21, 1.21}} *)

ListPlot[Table[{n,n}, {n,10^-2,1.4,0.05}], Joined -> True, Frame -> True,PlotRange ->{{0.,1.4},{0.,1.4}},GridLines ->Automatic]
```

My MAT version

```
$Version
(* 13.0.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (December 3, 2021)*)
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include the code you used to generate the plot. Without it, we can't tell you what went wrong

Comment: What version are you using? I get this result: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dj9Wc.jpg

Comment: I use MAT version 13

Comment: I got https://i.stack.imgur.com/0xcF5.png and https://i.stack.imgur.com/XgToY.png

Comment: @Gallagher put your `$Version` output on your question.

Comment: Did you set `PrintPrecision` to a large value by chance? (Like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GlTQ3.png)  Try something like `Style[ListPlot[...], PrintPrecision -> 6]`. If you're not sure what your `PrintPrecision` is set to, evaluate `Options[$FrontEnd, PrintPrecision]`.

Comment: @Michael E2, Options[$FrontEnd, PrintPrecision] gives {PrintPrecision -> 16}. I have a serious numerical problem to solve. Please, can you give me your email to contact you?

Comment: Try evaluating `SetOptions[$FrontEnd, PrintPrecision -> 10]` to change your global option setting for `PrintPrecision`, then re-evaluate your `ListPlot`. (MichaelE2's `Style` suggestion should work by itself too, though.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As [thorimur](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/63584/thorimur) and [Michael E2](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/4999/michael-e2) said , I just applied

```
SetOptions[$FrontEnd,PrintPrecision -> 10]
```

to change the global option setting for PrintPrecision. I get

[image]

Thank you all.